# PCL project not built in active configuration

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

So I was just handed this project to get it working on an iPad, however every time I try to test it on the iPad (debug|iPhone) it shows the project not built in active configuration for one of the PCLs. [With Debug|iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npIQ2.png). The other is attached just fine. When I switch to Debug|iPhoneSimulator however it links perfectly. 
[With Debug|iPhoneSimulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e0qe.png).
I need to create an .ipa file so I desperately need to be able to run this with the debug|iPhone setting.

What gives?

Comment: Build --> Configuration Manager

Comment: [Here's the configuration mapping](https://imgur.com/FYTnor7)

Comment: have you tried using Configuration Manager to edit your build config to do what you want?

Comment: I don't know how to get to the configuration manager honestly. It's not under  Build.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396